# What exactly is this procedure involving orange cases and slits beneath the eyes?

Tags: la-femme-nikita-tv

In the late 90s television series ***[La Femme Nikita](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/La_Femme_Nikita)***, subjects are interrogated by Section One in the so-called "White Room".  When they are not immediately forthcoming or cooperative, they are sometimes subjected to a particular treatment that, to my knowledge, is not shown on screen.

Two rather taciturn technicians will enter the room, one male and one female, carrying orange cases.  The next time we see the subject, he or she has a horizontal slit under each eye and is much more suggestible.  In some instances, the technicians have used the word "saturation" in conjunction with the procedure.  In one Season 3 episode ("Someone Else's Shadow"), a particular recipient of the procedure is still quite lucid and in control of his faculties, but describes it as excruciating and would cooperate in order to not endure it again.

[image]

**What do the orange cases contain?  What is the procedure and why does it leave slits beneath the eyes?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having just rewatched the entire series, there is exactly one scene that partially illustrates the procedure.  This scene is in the fourth season episode **"Hell Hath No Fury"**.

The subject is Leon (played by Colm Feore), the chief strategist for Red Cell.  As he is being interrogated, the technicians take out from their orange case a screwdriver-like surgical device into which they insert a small metallic disc near the end.  There is a thin drill bit at the very end that begins rotating when they turn the device on. The case contains further discs, a scalpel, and various pins and/or needles. Madeline (Section One's chief interrogator) pauses the procedure and warns that

> **"Their work won't be temporary"**

in regards to the procedure.  This is all we see and hear.

One might surmise that the slits beneath the eyes are cut by the disc on the device, or by the scalpel, but we don't see enough to know.